# Ajaxplorer - HTTP Error 404

Tags: php, http, http-status-code-404, pydio

I have a problem with the Ajaxplorer. I have configured it for uploading and downloading files and this is also working very well but just when the files are smaller than 100M. When I am trying to upload a bigger file there appears a I/O Error with an HTTP Error 404 (The upload is shown as completed but than the error appears).

Here is the configuration background:

- PHP is running on a Windows Server 2008 R2
- The max. uploading memory size is 2G (configured in the php.ini. This value is also shown in the
  Ajaxplorer)
- All relevant folder are writeable (i have configured the php session file and also in the
  Ajaxplorer the temp file and after every uploading error i find in these directory a temporary
  file so i think it´s writable)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your post_max_size as well?

```
--- php.net---
Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload.
To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize.
If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also
affects file uploading.
```

More info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: Yes sure and my configured size appears also in the configration of the Ajaxplorer.